# RoR4: Handling requests to a specific endpoint with another process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'd love to divide end-points to two types.

One is for normal request, and the other is only to handle webhook requests.

Is this possible to set up another process for webhook handling, and prevent the webhook from blocking the normal request?

I'll go for Unicorn for the application server, and Nginx for web server.